# Easyjson sticks on _easy file creating

Tags: go, marshalling

[Easyjson](https://github.com/mailru/easyjson) works well for simple codes, but it sticks when i run  `easyjson -run filename.go` for code that looks like:

```
package pack3

import (
    "myProj/pack1/pack1_1"
    "myProj/pack2"
    "sync"
)

type myStruct struct {
    sync.RWMutex
    Name    string          
    a   map[string]map[string]bool
    b   map[string]map[string]int
    c   map[string]float32           
    d   map[string]int
    e   []string               
    f   map[string]pack1_1.struct1   
    g   map[string]pack2.struct2 
}
```

There is no error when it sticks, but two files are created(filename_easy.go.tmp and easyjson_bootstrp[random_number].go).

Comment: Data type of field `f` and `g` is unexported. Easyjson should report those error.

Comment: I delete both of them, but it still sticks. I delete sync.RWMutex, now it works. So there are some problems with sync.RWMutex.

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue. Without `f` and `g` field (i.e. `sync.RWMutex` is not removed), easyjson is able to generate the file by invoking `easyjson -all filename.go`.

Comment: I test it again, it works! So how can i use imported structs ?!

Comment: You need to export your struct in order to be accessible from other package (i.e. the first letter of the struct's name must be upper case letter). For more detail, see [Exported Identifiers](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Exported_identifiers).

Comment: Thank you. But the main problem was other marshaller package(ffjson) that was used simultaneously.It's needed to run easyjson command on imported structs too.